# The notion of "holes" in topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, soft-question

I was discussing with a friend about my very basic understanding of topology that it was "basically about holes" and she mentioned to me that the notion of holes was more complicated in higher dimensions. For $2$-dimensional surfaces in $3$-dimensional space we have the idea of genus that identifies a surface uniquely by the number of holes it has, but it occurred to me that in higher dimensions that this might not hold for higher dimensional surfaces and holes.

> In four dimensions, for example, is there a counterexample where the Betti numbers are the same for two topological spaces but they are not homeomorphic?

I apologise if the question is not precise, but this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: Short answer is yes. You might find the article on [Homology spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere) interesting. Homology spheres are manifolds with the same homology (and therefore betti numbers) as a sphere of the appropriate dimension. There are examples in the article of homology spheres not homeomorphic to spheres, but I'm not an expert here either, so I can't flesh this out into a proper answer.

Comment: Henri Poincare made the same mistake at first: He thought that, like for surfaces, homology of a compact manifold determines the manifold. Then he found an example...

Comment: For 4d examples, see $\S 3$ of Scorpan's *The Wild World of $4$-Manifolds*.

Comment: Also, note that this problem also occurs in dimension two. The homology of a torus is exactly the same as the homology of two circles glued to a 2-sphere at a point. In fact, for any topological space $X$ with homology groups $\mathbb{Z}^k$ for varying $k$, spheres of varying dimension can be glued together so that the resulting space has the same homology as $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the examples and suggested reading! Very interesting!